# Create dictionary from table in Document

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python document which contains a page and a table.
With the following function I can print the keys (which is the first row of the table):

```
from trp import Document

def do_test(json_data):
    doc = Document(json_data)
    for page in doc.pages:
        for table in page.tables:
            keys = table.rows[0]
            print(keys)
```

Output:

```
[VAR1 ][VAR2 ][VAR3 ][VAR4 ][VAR5 ]
```

When I print the second and third row:

```
    print(table.rows[1])
    print(table.rows[2])
    ...
```

Output:

```
[Val1A ][Val1B ][Val1C ][Val1D ][Vald1E ]
[Val2A ][Val2B ][Val2C ][Val2D ][Vald2E ]
...
```

I want to create 2 dictionaries like this:

```
dic1 =  {
  "VAR1": "Val1A",
  "VAR2": "Val1B",
  "VAR3": "Val1C",
  "VAR4": "Val1D",
  "VAR5": "Val1E"
}
```

and

```
dic1 =  {
  "VAR1": "Val2A",
  "VAR2": "Val2B",
  "VAR3": "Val2C",
  "VAR4": "Val2D",
  "VAR5": "Val2E"
}
```

How can I create this by updating the `do_test` function?

Comment: The "zip" function can create tuples from two or more lists which can be used by "dict" function to create the dictionary.

Comment: Can you please provide a demo dictionary for testing purposes?

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answer without knowing what a "python document` is (i.e. what's in your `Document` class).

Comment: I use: from trp import Document

Comment: My rows are oftype: trp.Row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
def do_test(json_data):
    doc = Document(json_data)
    for page in doc.pages:
        for table in page.tables:
            keys = table.rows[0]
            row1 = table.rows[1]
            row2 = table.rows[2]

            dict1 = dict(zip(keys, row1))
            dict2 = dict(zip(keys, row2))

            return dict1, dict2
```

I don't know quite well the structure returned by `doc.pages`, `doc.tables` and `table.rows`.

Comment: I use trp import Document and my rows are of type: trp.Row